# "Перенести" сохранения в другой проект

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Если я в Google Play загружу обновление, создав новый проект, но с тем же пакетом, с тем же ключом и у SharedPreferences будет то же имя, то останутся ли все сохранения, или все пропадет?

Comment: Все останется. Вы можете сделать закрытый бета тест в консоли разработчика. Станьте участником бета теста и протестируйте обновление